# how to update particular coloumn using cursor in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, oracle9i

I've got a problem here. I have two tables `pp_gabungan` and `jharga`. `Jharga` is used to store budget value, on the other hand `pp_gabungan` is used to saved data of procurements of books.
I need to update `eks` field on `pp_gabungan` table automaticly using cursor.
for example as long as the price total which contain from the `sum of (eks*harga)` is less than `budget`, the value of eks field should be increased by one. But the problem is this code works, but it updates just one time.
it shouldn't stop incrementing as long as the `sum(eks*harga)` is less than `budget`. Could you guys help me whether i should add more loop ? if yes.. how should it be?
Here is my code :

```
DECLARE
bb jharga.budget%type;
tharga jharga.budget%type;

 CURSOR eksupdate IS
   SELECT 
isbn,judul,frekuensi,stok,harga,prioritas,eks,kelompok,bobot
   FROM  pp_gabungan 
   FOR UPDATE OF eks NOWAIT;
   autoeks eksupdate%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN eksupdate;   -- rows are locked.
   select budget into bb from jharga;
   select sum(eks*harga) into tharga from pp_gabungan;
     LOOP
       FETCH eksupdate INTO autoeks;      
       --EXIT WHEN eksupdate%NOTFOUND;
       tharga:=(autoeks.eks*autoeks.harga);
      IF  tharga <= bb  THEN
         UPDATE pp_gabungan 
          SET eks = autoeks.eks+1
          WHERE CURRENT OF eksupdate ;
       END IF;
       exit when tharga > bb;
     END LOOP;
     --COMMIT;  -- rows are unlocked.
   CLOSE eksupdate;
end;
```

Comment: It seems that what you want to find out is how many books you can buy given the price and budget.  If that's what you want why not just set `pp_gabungan.EKS = TRUNC(bb / harga)`?  This would set it directly without any looping.  If you insist on looping, try changing `IF tharga <= bb THEN` to `WHILE tharga <= bb LOOP`.

Comment: Also, note that the `SELECT`s from `jharga` and `pp_gabungan` don't have a `WHERE` clause so I suspect they won't work as you'd like them to.

Comment: i already try you suggest @BobJarvis But it is very long to execute when i used while-loop .... I dont put "where" clause in my "select" because i want to update eks field in all of tables :). I used loop because i want the update event always on as long as the sum of (eks*harga) less than budget :)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your requirement correctly, you want to increment the `eks` column by 1 for all rows, as long as the total of `eks*harga` for all rows is within the budget. After first pass, if there is budget still left, you want to repeat the process all over again.

I have modified, the opening of cursor using `FOR` loop, as i'm comfortable with this syntax.

```
DECLARE
  bbs       jharga.budget%TYPE;
  tharga    jharga.budget%TYPE;
  balance   NUMBER;

  CURSOR eksupdate
  IS
     SELECT        isbn, judul, frekuensi, stok, harga, prioritas, eks,
                   kelompok, bobot
              FROM pp_gabungan
     FOR UPDATE OF eks NOWAIT;
BEGIN
  --get the allotted budget
  SELECT budget
    INTO bbs
    FROM jharga;

  --get the total amount
  SELECT SUM (eks * harga)
    INTO tharga
    FROM pp_gabungan;

  balance := bbs - tharga;                              -- the balance amount

  --as long as the balance is more than zero , the cusor will be repeatedly called.
  -- also note that i've given a name to the loop, loop1
  <<loop1>>
  WHILE balance > 0
  LOOP

     --for loop to open/fetch the cursor, this has been given name loop2
     <<loop2>>
     FOR i IN eksupdate
     LOOP
        --if the balance amount is less than that of harga, exit from both the loops
        EXIT loop1 WHEN balance < i.harga;

        --if balance amount is more than harga, update the eks by 1
        UPDATE pp_gabungan
           SET eks = autoeks.eks + 1
         WHERE CURRENT OF eksupdate;

        --decrease the balance by harga
        balance := balance - i.harga;
     END LOOP loop2;
  END LOOP loop1;

  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
     ROLLBACK;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: thankyou @Horrendous_Space_Kabl ... I'll try your suggest code :)

Comment: thankyou @[Horrendous_Space_Kabl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/646591/horrendous-space-kablooie) ... I'll try your suggest code :) – K febrina 2 hours ago 
 
@Horrendous Thanks seems like you compared the balance with the price of each row table.Then you increment the eks field when it is less than the balance ... It worked really .. But after i tried yours the rest budget is still big enough ..How should i optimize the rest of budget not more than 500.000 ?so with this loop it should be countinued as long as the rest budget not over than 500.000

Comment: @K febrina, I don't understand the modified code. Isn't your budget selected from `jharga` table? What is `maxbud` variable.? if you want to limit your budget to 500000, simply use, `LEAST (bbs, 500000)` while calculating balance. `balance := LEAST (bbs, 500000)- tharga;`. Why are you opening the cursor before the while loop? And delete your answer and post it as an update to the question.

Comment: [Horrendous](http://stackoverflow.com/users/646591/horrendous-space-kablooie)first of all i'll try your suggest with "Least(bbs,500000)"..Thanks for your help.I open the cursor because it get error on  UPDATE pp_gabungan SET eks = autoeks.eks + 1 , so that i open the cursor , which mean autoeks is variable fetched from cursor 'eksupdate'

Comment: @[Hprrendous](http://stackoverflow.com/users/646591/horrendous-space-kablooie)its true that the increment of eks should countinuesly as long as it is not bigger than budget .. But if you look at the amount of balance its still big enough.. i just want to try optimize the rest of badget ,balance, as minimum as possible .. the minimum values is 500.000 , so it should increment as long as not over budget and also the balance is not more than 500.000 :)